# Outlook addin - code: 5001, message: "An internal error has occurred."

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

`Hello.
I'me developing an Outlook Addin. When displaying a confirm dialog, i'm getting the following error when hitting the "YES" option when using the Outlook Web Version. When using the installed Windows version, it works well.

`OSF.DDA.Error {name: 'Internal Error', message: 'An internal error has occurred.', code: 5001}`

The code to display the dialog:

```
async function confirmDelete() {
 
    var env = '#{env}#';
    var url = window.location.origin + "/" + env + "/confirmDialog.html";
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 10, width: 20, displayInIframe: true }, dialogCallback);
}

function dialogCallback(asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "block";
        var uiStrings = UIStrings().getLocaleStrings(Office.context.displayLanguage);
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerText = uiStrings.UnexpectedErrorMessageLabel;
        dialog.close();
    }
    else {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, messageHandler);
    }
}

function messageHandler(arg) {
    if ('Yes' == arg.message) {
        var selectedCboxes = getSelectedCheckBox("chkFile");
        for (var k = 0; k < selectedCboxes.length; k++) {
            callBackEnd(selectedCboxes[k].id);
        }
        dialog.close();
    } else if ('No' == arg.message) {
        dialog.close();
    }
}
```

The dialog itself:

```
import { UIStrings } from './uiStrings';

if (!window.Promise) {
    window.Promise = Office.Promise;
}

var uiStrings = {};
Office.onReady((info) => {
    uiStrings = UIStrings().getLocaleStrings(Office.context.displayLanguage);
    setPageTranslatedLabels();
});

function setPageTranslatedLabels() {
    document.getElementById("btnYes").value = uiStrings.YesButtonLabel.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById("btnNo").value = uiStrings.NoButtonLabel.toUpperCase();
    document.getElementById("lblConfirm").innerHTML = uiStrings.ConfirmMessageLabel;
}

async function yesOption() {
    Office.context.ui.messageParent(uiStrings.YesButtonLabel);
}

async function noOption() {
    Office.context.ui.messageParent(uiStrings.NoButtonLabel);
}

window.yesOption = yesOption;
window.noOption = noOption;
```

I am new to office.js, but i followed the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)

Can you help me, please?

The DefaultMinVersion setting on my manifest it's 1.8.

I've tried setting the "targetOrigin" option on the popup itself and did not work.`

EDIT: this is occurring when using axios to perform a REST call to the backend in order to delete a file.

Comment: Why do you need to mark functions as `async` when they don't run any async code?

Comment: From the description it is not clear what is failing. Do you see any API call to outlook failing? If yes, please share basic code that can be used to reproduce the issue.